# Larger drop down menu for ipywidgets interact

Tags: ipywidgets

Is it possible to make the input form for the ipywidget interact larger? 
When I use the following code, for example, the field is to small for the title and it looks messy.

```
# python code to run in jupyter notebook
%pylab inline
from ipywidgets import interact
def f(x):
    plot(range(10))
    title(x)
interact(f, x=['AbCd'*10])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Swapping your interact for an interactive will let you return the final widget, modify it, and *then* display it.

2) Manually specify the layout of the dropdown by finding the first child of the interactive, then setting the layout width in pixels. In a forthcoming release it looks like you will be able to set `width='initial'` to size automatically. ([revelant github issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2051))

---

```python
# python code to run in jupyter notebook
%pylab inline
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, Layout
def f(x):
    plot(range(10))
    title(x)
int_widget = interactive(f, x=['AbCd'*10])
int_widget.children[0].layout = Layout(width='500px')
display(int_widget)
```

[image]